# how to update table in a subview?

Tags: uitableview, subview

Im adding a subview using

`[self.view addSubview:self.patientsView];

   self.currentTabView = self.patientsView;`

Then i want to update a table inside the subview,I have a button "add" which adds values to database in the subview.
I want them to be updated in the table as soon as they are added to database.
I'm using an NSMutable array to get values from database

```
 patientsName=[[NetMDDatabase sharedInstance] getAllPatientsName];
```

Please help me.

Comment: You need to reload the tableview after setting the datasource.

Comment: thanks, [self.tableView reloadData];
I hope this is the code..but where will i do it, I'l aslo have to update the array ryt?

Comment: after updating array, you need to put this line of code.

Comment: xactly where these have to be done?

Comment: You are updating right,  patientsName=[[NetMDDatabase sharedInstance] getAllPatientsName]; [self.tableview reloadData];

Comment: Where you are updating array, that next line put reloadData.